# how to use error response in google smart home action

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

according to the google's guide [Error responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#error_responses), I can return an error response when some errors occur in my cloud service.So, I want to try:

```
{
    "requestId": "13711695294173375391",
    "payload": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "status": "ERROR",
                "ids": [
                    "5a1cbc26e4b0532d095e72a0"
                ],
                "errorCode": "authExpired"
            }
        ],
        "errorCode": "authExpired"
    }
}
```

but this syntax doesn't work.what's the correct usage of error response，can anyone give me a example？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two examples of errors that you can use as a basis for returning a problem with a device or fulfillment in general. It looks like you are using both, but you should use it at one of those levels, ie. either

```
{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [{
      "ids": ["456"],
      "status": "ERROR",
      "errorCode": "deviceTurnedOff"
    }]
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "payload": {
    "errorCode": "notSupported"
  }
}
```

Comment: but I want to know what happens when I return the "auth expired" error？

Comment: >A:Google will request the new token using "refresh_token" >B:Google just tell the user "Encountered an error for **" and do nothing.I think that A is more reasonable, but it is actually B

Comment: If you want Google to request a new token, you will have to do that logic in the token endpoint that you define in the AoG console.

Comment: Are there any tutorials for this?

Comment: Not specifically for Smart Home. You can probably look at general OAuth tutorials